# Loop through PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php

I am trying to loop through a multidimensional array but in the foreach loop it just outputs error

> index 'name' not found. index 'calories' not founder

```
        foreach($responsex['foods'] as $fx5)
        {
            echo($fx5['name']);
            echo($fx5['calories']);
        }
```

Response: i.e. **$responsex**

> array ( 'encodedId' => '4H8xxx', 'displayName' => 'sam', )array(3) {
>   ["foods"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(5) { ["isFavorite"]=> bool(false)
>   ["logDate"]=> string(10) "2016-04-15" ["logId"]=> int(7139364449)
>   ["loggedFood"]=> array(10) { ["accessLevel"]=> string(6) "PUBLIC"
>   ["amount"]=> int(2) ["brand"]=> string(0) "" ["calories"]=> int(574)
>   ["foodId"]=> int(536497687) ["locale"]=> string(5) "en_AU"
>   ["mealTypeId"]=> int(7) ["name"]=> string(14) "Potato Pudding"
>   ["unit"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(91) ["name"]=> string(3) "cup"
>   ["plural"]=> string(4) "cups" } ["units"]=> array(8) { [0]=> int(6754)
>   [1]=> int(91) [2]=> int(256) [3]=> int(279) [4]=> int(226) [5]=>
>   int(180) [6]=> int(147) [7]=> int(389) } } ["nutritionalValues"]=>
>   array(6) { ["calories"]=> int(574) ["carbs"]=> float(49.16) ["fat"]=>
>   float(34.98) ["fiber"]=> float(3.6) ["protein"]=> float(16.1)
>   ["sodium"]=> int(1524) } } [1]=> array(5) { ["isFavorite"]=>
>   bool(false) ["logDate"]=> string(10) "2016-04-15" ["logId"]=>
>   int(7138517833) ["loggedFood"]=> array(10) { ["accessLevel"]=>
>   string(6) "PUBLIC" ["amount"]=> int(1) ["brand"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["calories"]=> int(359) ["foodId"]=> int(535239347) ["locale"]=>
>   string(5) "en_AU" ["mealTypeId"]=> int(7) ["name"]=> string(54) "Fish,
>   Noodles and Vegetables in Cheese Sauce (Mixture)" ["unit"]=> array(3)
>   { ["id"]=> int(91) ["name"]=> string(3) "cup" ["plural"]=> string(4)
>   "cups" } ["units"]=> array(8) { [0]=> int(6837) [1]=> int(91) [2]=>
>   int(256) [3]=> int(279) [4]=> int(226) [5]=> int(180) [6]=> int(147)
>   [7]=> int(389) } } ["nutritionalValues"]=> array(6) { ["calories"]=>
>   int(359) ["carbs"]=> float(28.01) ["fat"]=> float(14.05) ["fiber"]=>
>   float(2.9) ["protein"]=> float(29.08) ["sodium"]=> int(534) } } [2]=>
>   array(5) { ["isFavorite"]=> bool(false) ["logDate"]=> string(10)
>   "2016-04-15" ["logId"]=> int(7138326866) ["loggedFood"]=> array(10) {
>   ["accessLevel"]=> string(6) "PUBLIC" ["amount"]=> int(1) ["brand"]=>
>   string(0) "" ["calories"]=> int(157) ["foodId"]=> int(536493638)
>   ["locale"]=> string(5) "en_AU" ["mealTypeId"]=> int(7) ["name"]=>
>   string(11) "Cashew Nuts" ["unit"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(226)
>   ["name"]=> string(2) "oz" ["plural"]=> string(2) "oz" } ["units"]=>
>   array(4) { [0]=> int(226) [1]=> int(180) [2]=> int(147) [3]=> int(389)
>   } } ["nutritionalValues"]=> array(6) { ["calories"]=> int(157)
>   ["carbs"]=> float(8.56) ["fat"]=> float(12.43) ["fiber"]=> float(0.9)
>   ["protein"]=> float(5.17) ["sodium"]=> int(3) } } } ["goals"]=>
>   array(2) { ["calories"]=> int(1161) ["estimatedCaloriesOut"]=>
>   int(1411) } ["summary"]=> array(7) { ["calories"]=> int(1090)
>   ["carbs"]=> float(85.73) ["fat"]=> float(61.46) ["fiber"]=> float(7.4)
>   ["protein"]=> float(50.35) ["sodium"]=> int(2061) ["water"]=> int(0) }
>   }

Comment: Can you create an 3v4l.org for us to use. Your array is quite big to debug with.

Comment: plz show result using print_r or json_encode

Answer (score 1):

you can recursively iterate through the arrays and print them as follows as key value pairs.

```
<?php 
//initially call the function
print_array($responsex);

function print_array($array){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        //recursively print the array
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo("Array : ".$key."\n");
            print_array($value);
        }
        else{
            echo($key." => ".$value);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You can define additional tasks other than printing them with the above code.

**Edit**:

if you are sure that the array is two dimensional, no need to go recursively.

```
<?php 
//initially call the function
print_array($responsex);

//if you are sure that the array is two dimensional, no need to go recursively.
function print_array($array){
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            if($key==="foods"){
                var_dump($array[$key]);
            }
        }
        else{
            echo($key." => ".$value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This just gives me the name of the inner array "foods". It outputs Array : foods. I need to access the values within the "foods" array

Comment: When outing echo ($v) in the inner foreach, just returns an array. When I var_dump its basically the array in the "food" index in initial response

Comment: Ahh, yes, you can use var_dump and get the whole array at once.

Comment: But I need to access the values inside the food array, not return the array. When I echo $(v) it gives me error "Array to string conversion"

Comment: Since you have arrays under 'foods' key. you need to go for a recursive method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way..

```
<?php

 $keys = array_keys($data);// put your array name as a place of $data
    $iterations = count($array[$keys[0]]);

    for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        $data = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $data[$key] = $value[$i];
        }
        print_r($data);
    }

?>
```